# Does anyone know why I am getting a null object reference when trying to push firebase data into android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a project to push data from a firebase real time database into an android application using android studio. I have already been successfully able to display data from other certain parts of the database but I am having trouble displaying data from a portion of the database labeled "TH" and I am not sure why.
Here is my code for reference:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class mcu2temphumid extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mcu2temphumid);
        TextView temp1 = findViewById(R.id.temp);
        TextView temp2 = findViewById(R.id.temp4);
        TextView temp3 = findViewById(R.id.temp5);
        // ethy4 = findViewById(R.id.ethy4);
        Button buttonreferesh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refreshmcu1temp2);
        Button buttonback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backmcu1temp2);
        DatabaseReference rootDatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MCU 2").child("TH").child("Sensor 1");//.child("TH").child("Sensor 1");
        DatabaseReference rootDatabaseref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MCU 2").child("TH").child("Sensor 1");
        DatabaseReference rootDatabaseref3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MCU 2").child("TH").child("Sensor 1");
        //DatabaseReference rootDatabaseref4 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MCU 1").child("Ethylene").child("Sensor 4");
        buttonback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //this section will allow the button to perform the method call when the button is pressed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivitymain();
            }
        });
        buttonreferesh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //this section will allow the button to perform the method call when the button is pressed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivityrefresh();
            }
        });
        rootDatabaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String data = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                Double z = Double.parseDouble(data);
                temp1.setText(String.valueOf(z));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        rootDatabaseref2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String data = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                Double z = Double.parseDouble(data);
                temp2.setText(String.valueOf(z));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        rootDatabaseref3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String data = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                Double z = Double.parseDouble(data);
                temp3.setText(String.valueOf(z));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
    public void openActivityrefresh(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, mcu2temphumid.class); //causes the subordinate activity file to be opened, redirects to new layout
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openActivitymain(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MCU2.class); //causes the subordinate activity file to be opened, redirects to new layout
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of my database in firebase:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrN92.jpg)

The following is the error I am receiving:

```
2022-09-19 08:53:49.900 18098-18098/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 18098
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.mcu2temphumid$3.onDataChange(mcu2temphumid.java:51)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6747)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

As mentioned before, I have used nearly identical code to successfully display data from other portions of the database, so I am not sure what the problem is. From my understanding getting a null object reference would indicate that there isnt any value being taken in for String data, but I clearly gave values to the corresponding entries in my database. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: At which particular line of code ae you getting that error?

Comment: @ temp1.setText(String.valueOf(z));

Comment: That means `temp1` is null, check that you used the correct ID to look it up (matches what's in the XML file you are using for that activity)